Validate a generic collection using SetValidator in Fluentvalidation
I am trying to validate a generic type:
public class Request<T> where T : class
{
    public int Test { get; set; }

    public List<T> Records { get; set; } = [];
}

How do I set the SetValidator? I am encountering the error: Cannot convert from ‘QuotasValidator’ to ‘FluentValidation.Validators.IPropertyValidator<Request<T>, T>’ . I have also tried RuleForEach(request => request.Records.OfType<Quotas>()).SetValidator(new QuotasValidator());
public class RequestValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<Request<T>> where T : class
{
    public RequestValidator()
    {
        //if (T is typeOf(..))
            RuleForEach(request => request.Records).SetValidator<T>(new QuotasValidator());
    }
}

Is there an out-of-the-box solution available, or do I need to implement a custom one? I Looked at Polymorphic Validator. Perhaps there is an approach I am missing?

I finally ended up using the Polymorphic Validator:
public interface IRequest<T>
{
    public List<T> Records { get; set; }
}

public class QuotaRequest : IRequest<Item>
{
    public List<Item> Records { get; set; } = [];
}

public class RequestValidator : AbstractValidator<QuotaRequest>
{
    public RequestValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(request => request.Records).SetValidator(new ItemValidator());
    }
}

